# Win2D: Create a round image

Tags: uwp, win2d

I'm developing a C#/UWP app and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to create/draw a round image from a square image in Win2D?

In XAML I could simply do this:

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="myImage.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

How can I get the same result using Win2D ?

Comment: Can't you just use a [CanvasImageBrush](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Brushes_CanvasImageBrush.htm) to [draw a filled ellipse](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_FillEllipse.htm)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was using CanvasGeometry and DrawingSession.CreateLayer to achieve this but using a CanvasImageBrush as you pointed out is a simpler approach so I'll be using that.